# How to add functionality to an instantiated widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create a package where I add some functionality to a `BottomNavigationBar`. I want a generic helper that when used, wraps a bottom nav widget with another widget and changes its `onTap` method. Unfortunately, `onTap` is final and cannot be changed. This forces me to create the `BottomNavigationBar` widget in the package code. This results in me having to delegate all properties of the `BottomNavigationBar` from the user.

Ideally, I want the user to pass me a navigation bar instance, and I add the functionality to it as long as the passed in widget has `currentIndex` and `onTap` properties settable.

How would you solve this?

### Edit

Code snippet for what I am trying to achieve:

```
class ExtendedBottomNav extends StatefulWidget {
  const ExtendedBottomNav({required this.bottomNavBar});

  final BottomNavigationBar bottomNavBar;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => ExtendedBottomNavState();
}

class ExtendedBottomNavState extends State<ExtendedBottomNav> {
  int _currentTabIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    widget.bottomNavBar.currentIndex = _currentTabIndex;
    widget.bottomNavBar.onTap = (int index) => {
      // Some code, using _currentTabIndex
    };

    return Scaffold(
      body: Text("Text"), // Some body
      bottomNavigationBar: widget.bottomNavBar,
    );
  }
}
```

This is not possible because `'onTap' can't be used as a setter because it's final.`

Comment: In what doyou want to change in the BottomNavigationBar ? Is it the design or something else ?

Comment: @Niteesh as I said, I want to change (or append code to) the `onTap` method of the passed in `BottomNavigationBar`

Comment: Can you add a code snippet of what you want to do? Since `onTap` is a expecting function, you can add your custom logic within a function you provide to the `onTap` for `BottomNavigationBar`

Comment: @RohanThacker I added a code snippet for what I am trying to do. I know my code doesn't work. I am asking, what should I do to get a similar result?

Answer (score 0):

i think you can do it by extending the BottomNavigationBar widget and override
the onTap funtion and tell user to pass the new subclass of BottomNavigationBar

```dart
class NewBottomNavigationBar extends BottomNavigationBar {
  NewBottomNavigationBar(List<BottomNavigationBarItem> items)
      : super(items: []);

  @override
  ValueChanged<int>? onTap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach (uses null safety). I've not used all the constructor parameters, you can modify as per your need.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: MyStatefulWidget(),
    );
  }
}

/// This is the stateful widget that the main application instantiates.
class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

/// This is the private State class that goes with MyStatefulWidget.
class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  static const TextStyle optionStyle =
      TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);
  static const List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    Text(
      'Index 0: Home',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 1: Business',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 2: School',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
  ];

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('BottomNavigationBar Sample'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: CustomBottomNavigationBar(bar:BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'Home',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.business),
            label: 'Business',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.school),
            label: 'School',
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
    ));
  }
}


class CustomBottomNavigationBar extends StatelessWidget {
  final BottomNavigationBar bar;
   CustomBottomNavigationBar({ required this.bar});
   
   BottomNavigationBar? customBar;
 
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    customBar = BottomNavigationBar(
      items: bar.items,
        currentIndex: bar.currentIndex,
        selectedItemColor: bar.selectedItemColor,
        onTap: (int index){

          // here you can add your additional code
          print("hi");
          
          if(bar.onTap != null)
            bar.onTap!(index);
        },
    );
    return Container(
    child:customBar);
  }
}
```

Without null safety

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: MyStatefulWidget(),
    );
  }
}

/// This is the stateful widget that the main application instantiates.
class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

/// This is the private State class that goes with MyStatefulWidget.
class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  static const TextStyle optionStyle =
      TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);
  static const List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    Text(
      'Index 0: Home',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 1: Business',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 2: School',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
  ];

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('BottomNavigationBar Sample'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: CustomBottomNavigationBar(bar:BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'Home',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.business),
            label: 'Business',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.school),
            label: 'School',
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
    ));
  }
}


class CustomBottomNavigationBar extends StatelessWidget {
  final BottomNavigationBar bar;
   CustomBottomNavigationBar({ @required this.bar});
   
   BottomNavigationBar customBar;
 
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    customBar = BottomNavigationBar(
      items: bar.items,
        currentIndex: bar.currentIndex,
        selectedItemColor: bar.selectedItemColor,
        onTap: (int index){
          print("hi");
          
          if(bar.onTap != null)
            bar.onTap(index);
        },
    );
    return Container(
    child:customBar);
  }
}
```